# "bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable" error on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, dll, git-bash

When I open `git bash` I get these messages:

```
          2 [main] bash (40164) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1301410/0x12A1410.
    This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
    Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
    and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
    reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
    installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
    are unable to find another

> Blockquote

 cygwin DLL.
          1 [main] bash 45888 fork: child -1 - forked process 40164 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
```

I also tried `ulimit -a` and got:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2032
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

And found this command in another similar question `ulimit -Sn unlimited && ulimit -Sl unlimited` and got this result:

```
bash: ulimit: -l: invalid option
ulimit: usage: ulimit [-SHabcdefiklmnpqrstuvxPT] [limit]
```

I also searched for `cygwin1.dll` in `CMD` and windows graphical search but couldn't find such file!

Comment: at least one is under `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\` otherwise the program will not work at all

Comment: @matzeri: this is the only `cygwin` file in that location: `cygwin-console-helper.exe`